# execute a command by screen in another user

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I'm trying to run a command on screen from another user, but I'm having trouble.

this is the command line:

```
sudo -u user123 screen -A -m -d -L screenlog.0 -S test123 ./my_program.
```

This is how I'm doing it:

```
sudo -u user123 bash -c screen -S test123 -p 0 -X stuff 'top^M'
```

but what i get is:

```
[screen is terminating]
```

and nothing is executed.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given an existing session started with `screen -S stuff` as user `user123`, I can execute commands in the existing session like this:

```
sudo -u user123 screen -p 0 -X stuff 'top\n'
```

Comment: thank you. It works perfect.